# Deadlock Caused due to (row level Locking and) delete then insert in an table with no constraints

Tags: deadlock, database-deadlocks

We have an online application which checks room availability. A procedure is used and it uses a table (with no constraints) temporarily to delete its contents first and then insert the searched rows (searched data using select queries in cursor). Another user from another session deletes the table data and inserts again the table data.

Some observations from deadlock graph:
1. Enqueue type is TX (after seeing the deadlock graph), so, this is definitely not locking due to unindexed foreign keys.

2. The mode the lock is being waited on is 'X' (exclusive), so there is row-level locking.

Comment: Can you share deadlock graph

Comment: Deadlock graph:            ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter

Comment: this is not a deadlock graph ,please upload one

Comment: Deadlock graph:
                       ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-000d0005-00034c41       212     689     X             61     454           X
TX-0016001c-0001150a        61     454     X            212     689           X

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Sorry, the graph I have posted is all text.Please copy it in notepad++ editor and it will be auto formatted properly.

Comment: Please reply if you need more information.